# How do I control the evaluation order of Angular validators?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Using Angular 1.5

I understand that angular validators get added to a field when the directive gets fired and then when the value of the control changes all the validators fire. I have 3 different validations of an amount field (correct characters, max length, and cannot be zero). I do not need to evaluate for cannot be zero if the field isn't a valid amount, but instead of going through all the valid amount checks a second time I'd like to check `control.$validator.amountFormat.`

Is there anyway to guarantee that the format validator that I built will occur before the greater than zero validator. I have many other scenarios than this.

This is what I have:

```
ctrl.$validators.amountFormat = (modelValue: string, viewValue: string) => {
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue)) {
        return true;
    }

    return isAmount(viewValue);
}

ctrl.$validators.amountGreaterThanZero = (modelValue: string, viewValue: string) => {
    if (!isAmount(viewValue)) {  //isAmount() is the function used to determine format
        return true;
    }

    return parseFloat(viewValue) > 0;
}
```

This is what I'd like to have:

```
ctrl.$validators.amountGreaterThanZero = (modelValue: string, viewValue: string) => {
    if (ctrl.$error.amountFormat) {
        return true;
    }

    return parseFloat(viewValue) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link explains that $validators fire after $parsers successfully complete. In the `Meet the $validators pipeline` section:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html

So instead of trying to get validators to fire before one another. I was able to write a parser that said (in plain terms) if the user enters a valid amount, store it in the modelValue, otherwise leave the modelValue blank.

```
ctrl.$parsers.push((viewValue: string) => {
    var modelReturnValue = '';

    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue)) { return modelReturnValue; }

    if (this.isAmount(viewValue)) {
        modelReturnValue = viewValue;
    }

    return modelReturnValue;
});
```

Then in my validators instead of using viewValue I can use modelValue

```
ctrl.$validators.amountFormat = (modelValue: string, viewValue: string) => {
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(viewValue)) {
        return true;
    }

    //format validator still has to check the viewValue because if the user doesnt type anything in we do not want to show a format error
    return isAmount(viewValue);
}
```

Optionally, the amountFormat validator could simply check if `viewValue != modelValue` since if the viewValue is a valid amount we are simply storing it as the modelValue.

```
ctrl.$validators.amountGreaterThanZero = (modelValue: string) => {
    //Because we are returning an empty string if the value is not a valid amount, we can comfortably say that the modelValue will be empty
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {  
        return true;
    }

    return parseFloat(modelValue) > 0;
}
```